# Cron Job is not working on discord.js, and why it doesn't give me any error?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to send a meet link daily at 8:00 pm
for testing purpose i set the time 2 min latter of the code run but it not working with no error

```js
client.on ("ready", () => {

    console.log(`${client.user.tag} Has logged in`)

let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob('00 20 * * *', () => {
         const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('996457970328158328');
         const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('996458112959643728');
         channel.send('Hey @everyone plz join todays scrum');
});
            
        
        scheduledMessage.start()

});
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug if your cron job is being executed by logging something in there? I haven't worked with discord.js, but you're trying to get the guild and channel from the cache; maybe it doesn't exist there?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing these two lines:

> ```
> const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('996457970328158328');
> const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('996458112959643728');
> ```

with:

> ```
> const guild = client.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.id == '996457970328158328');
> const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id == '996458112959643728');
> ```

Comment: bro last night i see the code is working. i means i just set the cronJob time to 00 20 * * * it means bot will send the message in 8pm but the bot sended the message in midnight 2:00 am 

I dont know why

Comment: It depends with the timezone of the server where your bot is hosted in
Try to use the `timeZone` parameter you can read about it in the cron documentation https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron

Comment: i used the timezone but it give me message in 2:00am and btw i uesd cronJob not node-cron